# Где надо логировать?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, исключения, логирование

Допустим есть приложение. Например asp.net mvc. Оно требует логирования тех или иных операций и исключений. Где наиболее правильно размещать операции записи в лог? Предположим наше приложение имеет контроллеры-действия. Внутри них вызываются некие сервисы. В сервисах заключена бизнес-логика которая что-то делает а также общается с репозиторием, который в свою очередь работает с базой данных. Как-то так:

```
// action в контроллере
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    _myService.DoSomething();
}

// метод в сервисе
public void DoSomething() 
{
    // тут какая-то бизнес-логика, 
    // например, мы что-то делаем с репозиторием
    _repository.DoSomethingMore();
    // что-то еще
}

// метод в репозитории
public void DoSomethingMore() 
{
    // здесь мы что-то делаем с базой
    using(var context = new Context())
    {
        // вот тут происходит исключение
        // которое надо залогировать
    }        
}
```

Логирование выпролняется статическими методами некоего класса `Log`:

```
Log.Error(exception);
```

Вопрос в том, где выполнять логирование? В репозитории? Вряд ли он вообще должен что-то знать об этом. В сервисе? Мне кажется, что это плохая  идея связывать бизнес-логику со статическим классом логгера и делать зависимость таким образом. В контроллере? Или где-то ещё? Подскажите пожалуйста как делать такие вещи правильно?

Comment: Логировать нужно вообще везде. Исключения, как правило, надо обрабатывать на самом верхнем уровне, который может это позволить.

Comment: @etki Что вы подразумеваете под верхнем уровнем?

Answer (score 1):

Логирование ошибок нужно выполнять там, где они возникают. Если ошибка в репозитарии, то логируем в репозитарии.